# Expected return for Craps Casino game

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the expected return for the Craps casino game. Can someone explain to me how to calculate it?

Comment: Craps is a game that requires total understanding of the underlying betting structure.  This is not an easy question to answer since bets can come in many different forms.

Answer (score 1):

A paper entitled "Expected Value and the Game of Craps" by Blake Thorton

Not only does it have exercises to work on while you learn, there's even a colorful craps table to look at so as to be inspired....

http://www.dehn.wustl.edu/~blake/courses/WU-Ed6021-2012-Summer/handouts/Expected_Value.pdf